# Как Set добавляет значения в коллекцию?

Tags: javascript, объекты, set

```
let set = new Set(['set', {key: 'value'}], ['set'], 'tree', 'tree');
```

Пишется, что Set может принимать в качестве значений любые типы данных - сложные и примитивные. Но в коде, который я написал, добавилось всего 2 значения - `['set']` и `{key: 'value'}`. Почему не добавляется строка - `'tree'`?

Также немного непонятно получается с объектом `{key: 'value'}` - почему он выбрасывается из массива с `'set'` (`['set', {key: 'value'}]`)? Это я так понимаю происходит, потому что строка `'set'` была передана в массиве, а массив все равно должен содержать только примитивные значения. Правильно я понимаю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `new Set(['set', {key: 'value'}], ['set'], 'tree', 'tree')` -> `new Set(['set', {key: 'value'}, ['set'], 'tree', 'tree'])`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy то есть строки должны быть в массиве, чтоб добавиться в набор. Зачем? Объект, как я вижу, тоже добавляется только в массиве

Comment: В set на вход подается МАССИВ элементов, любых, но один массив, а не переменные через запятую

Comment: `new Set([<любые объекты, которые вы хотите поместить в Set через запятую>])`.